# IIS web service responds on server, not from remote client

Tags: iis, web-services

I have installed a web service on a server running IIS (v6, as far as I can tell).  There is another service installed, which responds as expected.  My service responds correctly when a browser is pointed to localhost, but there is no response when a remote client tries to query the service.
Fiddler on the remote client simply reports a timeout.  Wireshark on the remote client shows no response at all from the server, no NACK, nothing.
Wireshark on the server detects no query at the relevant port (the service is installed on port 8080).  There are no relevant entries in the event viewer.
Obviously there is some issue of permissions or authentication. I have tried to compare my service to the service that works, but I have not been able to locate relevant parameters.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, when asking question, take the time to provide the minimum information: OS, software version, etc.

Comment: My apologies. The service is compiled for .NET 4.0. It is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter. I believe that the IIS version is 6, since that is what I see listed in the Windows Features list. Note also that it is not a firewall issue: port 8080 is open, and I still see the same issue when I turn off the firewall completely.

Comment: How do you connect to the service? Via a URL. What IP address comes up when you ping the URL? Is this IP address configured in IIS? It sounds like a DNS issue to me.

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't understand at all why Wireshark doesn't see anything coming into that port on the server when the firewall is off.

Comment: @Liam, I am using a raw IP address to connect right now, so DNS is out of the loop. I use that same IP address to connect via remote terminal, and to access the other service which does work.

Comment: And the site is installed as the default service on port 8080 for the IP address your using? There is no other site using the same IP address with a different host header?

Comment: IIS on Windows 2008 is version 7.  IIS6 was on Windows 2003.  They are completely different animals.  There are some components in the IIS7 installation that allow you to do management of IIS6.  This might be what you're seeing in the Windows Features list.

Comment: What kind of web service is it?  WCF?  And are the services installed in the root folder of your web site or are they subfolders under the root?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean, it must be IIS7. Yes, it is a WCF service, and they are installed in the root folder of the website.  Could this have to do with permissions on the specific folder?

Comment: And you're appending the port when you try to connect? A browser isn't going to know that your web site is running on port 8080.

Comment: Yes, I'm appending the port to the IP.